# Checkerboard Problem

Tags: summation, problem-solving, integers

Let $a$ and $b$ be any positive integers, and consider an $a\times b$ checkerboard.  Let $S(a,b)$ be the total number of different squares of any size on our $a\times b$ checkerboard. What are the values of $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if any, for which $$0.399<\frac{S(n,n)}{S(n,2n)}<0.401?$$  Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would I be heading in the right direction if I found an equation for $S(n,n)$ and an equation for $S(n,2n)$ and then try and isolate and solve for $n$?

Comment: Finding an eauation for S(a,b) would be enough, yes. The resulting ratio will probably be a monotonic function

Comment: Finding equations for S(n,n) and S(n,2n), lime you suggested, might actually be a lot easier than finding one for S(a,b) when I think about it

Comment: Number of squares on an $n\times n$ board is a standard puzzle. It's just $1+4+9+\cdots+n^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both $n\times n$ and $n\times2n$, the squares can have side length $1\le k\le n$. On the $n\times n$ board, there are $(n-k+1)^2$ squares of side length $k$; on the $n\times2n$ board there are $(n-k+1)(2n-k+1)$. Thus we have

$$
S(n,n)=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)^2=\sum_{j=1}^nj^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6
$$

and

$$
S(n,2n)=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)(2n-k+1)=\sum_{j=1}^nj(n+j)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\frac{n^2(n+1)}2=\frac{n(n+1)(5n+1)}6\;.
$$

The ratio is

$$
\frac{2n+1}{5n+1}\;,
$$

and this is less than $0.401$ for $n\ge120$.